# Concatenation of name and using concat again for a username?

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to pull out information from a database with PHP and have the following query:

```
$q = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) AS Name,
      (NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
      substring('Firstname',1,1, 'MiddleName'),
      left(MiddleName,1) AS MN,
      (LastName) AS LN
       FROM customer 
       Where FN.MN.LN = 'username'"; 
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
```

when I run this, I get info back but not the username, which I need:

```
$q = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) AS Name,
      (NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
      left('Firstname',1) as FN,
      left(MiddleName,1) AS MN,
      (LastName) AS LN 
            FROM customer".
```

Just stuck, have tried quite a few things and just can't get it to work.

Comment: Please provide us with some input data so we can test, you have a structure that is hard to follow with all your LEFT and SUBSTRINGS...

Comment: What is `FN.MN.LN`? Did you mean `CONCAT(FN,MN,LN)`?

Comment: it's variables for FirstName, MiddleName, LastName

Comment: @WendyCombs: Isn't `FN.MN.LN` a syntax error?

Comment: yea i get errors period whenever i try to put the name together the 2nd time.  example data  Bob Carter Jones - first part of concat = Jones, Bob.  which is fine, but i also need BCJones as a user name.  I tried the lefts, the strings the concats.. ack i'm stuck..lol sorry, so i tried the substring and the where clause..didn't work, the concat('FN'.'MN'.LN'), gives me an error also. nothing i've tried seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = "SELECT CONCAT(left(FirstName,1),left(MiddleName,1),LastName) AS UserName, CONCAT_WS(' ',LastName,FirstName) AS Name, (NewCustomerID) AS customerid FROM customer ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `FN`, `MN`, and `LN` are aliases, you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

```
HAVING FN.MN.LN = 'username'
```

Though, `FN.MN.LN` is a syntax error, I assume you meant `CONCAT(FN,MN,LN)`?

```
HAVING CONCAT(FN,MN,LN) = 'username'
```

Comment: still getting this error:  Customers:

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\Index.php on line 25

There are currently no records to show

Comment: That error is elsewhere.  Show us where's your running this query (and calling `mysqli_num_rows`).

Comment: <?php
echo '<h1>Customers:</h1>';
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');
$q = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) AS Name,
   (NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
   substring('Firstname',1,1, 'MiddleName'),
   left(MiddleName,1) AS MN,
   (LastName) AS LN
    FROM customer 
    HAVING CONCAT(FN,MN,LN) = 'username' "; 
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if ($num >0) {
 echo "<p> There are currently $num of customers.</p><br/>";

Comment: echo '<table width="200" border="1">
     <tr>
    <td>Customer ID</td>
    <td>Customer Name</td>
    <td>UserName</td>
     </tr>';
  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<tr><td>' . $row['customerid']. '</td><td>' . $row['Name'].'</td><td>' . $row['username'].'</td>
  
    
    </tr>'; }
 
  echo '</table>';
   mysqli_free_result ($r);
} else {
 echo '<p class="error">There are currently no records to show</p>';
}
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>




</body>
</html>

Comment: @WendyCombs: Guess there's still a mysql error.  Add `if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc))}` after `$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);`.

Comment: Parse error: parse error in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\Index.php on line 25

Comment: `if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc));}`  Oops, missed a `;`.  Try that.

Comment: still error - 
Parse error: parse error in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\Index.php on line 24  --$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q )if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc));}

Comment: @WendyCombs: `$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q ); if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc));}`  You forgot a `;` after `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Thought it needed it but wasn't for sure. lol.. r u on facebook? i can im you alllllllllllllll my questions..lol thank you

Comment: @WendyCombs: Let's keep the discussion here, so the community can help too.  Did you see any MySQL errors?

Comment: lol.. fine no stalking is suppose.. only 3 more weeks of php homework..yay!!

Comment: exact words used by instructor - Username (firstinitial + middleinitial + lastname)
o Build on the fly. Do not store in Db.
 - tips by teacher..none. so is it possible to run 2 queries and have them pull inside a table? or use 2 concats?

Comment: also if i pull out the left(firstname,1); etc for the 2nd command i get back information.

Comment: `HAVING CONCAT(FN,MN,LN) = 'username'` should work.  For debugging add `CONCAT(FN,MN,LN)` to your SELECT, to see what it's returning.

Comment: actually solved it..omg.. thank you so much..  here is how i did it.

Comment: $q = "SELECT CONCAT(left(FirstName,1),left(MiddleName,1),LastName) AS UserName,
   CONCAT_WS(' ',LastName,FirstName) AS Name,
   (NewCustomerID) AS customerid
    FROM customer ";

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the correct answer as a plain visible answer instead of leaving it buried in the (too many) comments. It will help others to find it...

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the query correctly, *Firstname* is a column name:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) AS Name,
    (NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
    LEFT(Firstname,1) as FN, 
    LEFT(MiddleName,1) AS MN,
    (LastName) AS LN
FROM customer
WHERE CONCAT(FN,MN,LN) = 'username'
```